# "FormatException: Duplicate setting 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol' found" in Azure Web App + Storage Connection Strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage, connection-string

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC App (Framework - not Core). In the Azure Portal, in Web App Configuration, I have set up several Azure Storage Connection Strings, for various application requirements.

I'm getting a very strange error occur whenever I attempt to read the connection strings. I get:

```
[FormatException: Duplicate setting 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol' found.]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.<Parse>b__0(String err) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\CloudStorageAccount.cs:525
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.ParseStringIntoSettings(String connectionString, Action`1 error) in c:\Program Files     (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\CloudStorageAccount.cs:993
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.ParseImpl(String connectionString, CloudStorageAccount& accountInformation, Action`1 error) in c:\Program Files     (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\CloudStorageAccount.cs:807
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(String connectionString) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\CloudStorageAccount.cs:525
```

As you can see, it traces back to `ParseStringIntoSettings` inside `CloudStorageAccount.cs`, part of the Storage Nuget library.

Here is the code in that library (from GitHub):

```
    private static IDictionary<string, string> ParseStringIntoSettings(string connectionString, Action<string> error)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string[] splitted = connectionString.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string nameValue in splitted)
        {
            string[] splittedNameValue = nameValue.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);

            if (splittedNameValue.Length != 2)
            {
                error("Settings must be of the form \"name=value\".");
                return null;
            }

            if (settings.ContainsKey(splittedNameValue[0]))
            {
                error(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Duplicate setting '{0}' found.", splittedNameValue[0]));
                return null;
            }

            settings.Add(splittedNameValue[0], splittedNameValue[1]);
        }

        return settings;
    }
```

I've checked the connection strings carefully, and they're all absolutely 100% right. Copied directly from the Azure portal itself. If I hard-code the connection strings, everything works perfectly, the problem surfaces only when I pull the connection strings from the configuration within the portal.

It's as if the `settings` IDictionary reference, which is clearly a local variable within `ParseStringIntoSettings` is static and not local, and is finding the `DefaultEndpointsProtocol` name/value from another connection string.

Code debugs and works perfectly locally, using web.config to store settings. This appears only to happen when picking the settings up from the portal instead.

Also, the error occurs if I put the storage connection string in App Settings and also in Connection Strings within the portal. Makes no difference.

ASP.NET MVC 4.8 Framework. Visual Studio 2017. Built using Azure DevOps and deployed into Azure Web App. For reasons of compatibility with Azure Functions, I'm using Storage 8.7, although I have tested in later versions and the problem persists.

Comment: Did you ever find cause of this? I am having exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

A very strange error. Try at my side, everything is fine.

I suggest you try to [remote debug apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio#remotedebug). You may be able to check the connection string you get from config file or portal configuration.

Comment: Weirdest error I've had in years! Couldn't resolve it so I recreated the web app in Azure from scratch and redeployed. Error didn't resurface.